# How to avoid creating an empty file with gsed?

Tags: linux, sed

Most of the sed-invocations redirect its output into the desired file. Which means, the file is created (by the invoking shell) even before sed is actually invoked...

Which, in turn, means, if sed had nothing to output, the file will be empty...

Is there a trick to have *no file at all* instead in such a situation?

The only things I can think of is either examine the file after sed finishes, or output to a temporary file and only move it into place, if not empty.

Both are ugly... Is there some better way? Would prefer a generic solution, but Linux- or gsed-only is Ok too.

Comment: To remove empty files: `[ -s "$file" ] || rm "$file"`

Comment: That's not a sed-construct, @John1024...

Comment: That's correct.  If you are looking for a `sed` (not shell) command that deletes empty files (as you know, the empty file is created by the shell, not `sed`), then you should update the question with this restriction.

Comment: I never once mention shell in my question, @John1024. And the very question asks about avoiding the very creation of such files, not removing them. Indeed, inside the question I state, that I _know_ how to check for emptiness of an existing file -- I just consider the creating-then-deleting pattern ugly.

Comment: You did mention the shell in your question:  You wrote: _"Which means, the file is created (by the invoking shell) "_.  I hope someone else is able to answer your question to your satisfaction.

Comment: sed's `w` command might help.

Comment: Indeed! @Cyrus, can you make this into a proper answer -- so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed's `w` command might help.

From `man sed`:

> `w filename`: Write the current pattern space to filename.